# How would you rebuild a time machine in the wilderness?

Tags: technology, technological-development, natural-resources

In my game the player travels to a parallel dimension and their time machine gets heavily damaged. So now they have to use the resources in the world to rebuild/repair it. We can assume that the player can easily mine for stone and ores as well as build the necessary tools like pickaxes and smelters.

For example: Crafting a battery to power it would require copper, iron and clay (in reference to the Baghdad battery). The player can mine for these, use a smelter to refine them and craft using a workbench.

So what could be the roadmap to rebuilding a the time machine?

Plus: You can cheat by using magic if you'd like to get creative ;)

Comment: I'm not certain if this is a world-building problem, as for the goal of creating a time machine, how else are we going to make one without magic if we ourselves don't even know how to build one in real life. For all intents and purposes I might as well give an answer along the lines of "use speedium to go faster than light and then go forwards or backwards in time depending on if you go east or west."

Comment: Bluntly put, without judicious hand-waving and magic, it is basically **impossible to repair a piece of space-age technology, let alone "future era" tech, in a "primitive" setting provided you don't already have spare parts and tools with you**. Sure, you might be able to fix cosmetic damage, oil hinges, or even patch a hole in a pressure vessel, but if a single semiconductor element that is critical to the operation of the machine breaks, you're screwed.

Comment: Your best bet would be trying to achieve immortality and then waiting for the industrial revolution. Attempting to build up a realistic tech base that can build semiconductors within a standard human lifetime if starting from nothing is impossible, even if you're the Emperor of a large nation and have millions of people willing to do what you order them to do.

Comment: Classic Star Trek.  Spock repairs their time machine with "stone knives and bear skins".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F226oWBHvvI

Comment: unless you provide the blueprints of that time machine to us, this is unanswerable.

Comment: i think the repair manual for this would have as point 1: "be rick sanchez"

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a complex, unknown scenario "repairing a time machine". When someone on this forum would give some -hypothetical - advice about the time machine's internals, you'd have a lot of work to go implement these procedures in your game ! And not every gamer is in for a CAD-exercise..

**Resources only**

Now suppose the time machine comes from a modern high-tech civilization. It would be able to repair itself, it only needs the resources. These resources must be located and collected in the game. When all resources are gathered, the "Repair" will be enabled and you show a nice animation of the reconstruction of the time machine. Maybe I'm too much of a 90's seek and gather  "adventurist", but this is how I would approach that part of the game.

You could add some puzzle challenge part in the end.. when all resources are gathered, the time machine pops up some kind of complicated button panel with alien buttons on it.. Requiring the gamer to experiment with the actions and see what happens..